# tensorflow sess does not close automatically

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a code as follows:

```
   import tensorflow as tf
   a = tf.constant([1,2,3])
   with tf.Session() as sess:
       print('12')
   print(sess.run(a))
```

However, I get results

```
   12
   [1 2 3]
```

when I run the code. It seems the sess does not close automatically. Can someone explain how it happens? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce it with tensorflow 1.7.

This has been fixed in version 1.8 of tensorflow.

Comment: hi Till, I am now using tensorflow 1.7 as well.  Does this mean we have to close the session using sess.close()  explicitly?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary.I think the bug will go away if you actually use sess within your `with`-statement